# Powershell - base64 encoded with key/passphrase

Tags: powershell, encryption, base64, citrix, one-time-password

With citrix netscaler update, the OTP is now encrepted in the active Directory attribute.

The **OTP explorer tool** created by Andreas Nick was working perfectly up to now.

https://www.andreasnick.com/102-otpedit.html

The citrix Documentation says that the OTP secret is now **encrypted by the certificate**. After the encryption, the HASH string that is stored in the Active Directory attribute looks like this.

OTP Secret
3DHAZHNBYLK72SFKVUOLU6E4ZE

Hash (in Active Directory)
jjtTl0YY3MGIF77HPcqYs2w2bAc=.sbntdorhH2Ju15c5.kbJ8_AP8Ytu7BiNuICEfkiSgOVJMudtNXgn2eStfoOGyV42v6VbzLA==

I tried to encrypt the OTP secret with the certificate used but they are a lot more caracters (346 in total - citrix encryption has 102).

On the citrix website it says that it is using base64 to encrypt the data.

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-adc/current-release/aaa-tm/authentication-methods/native-otp-authentication/otp-encryption-tool.html

I tried to use this code but the HASH is not good.

```
$enc      = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$string   = "3DHAZHNBYLK72SFKVUOLU6E4ZE"
$data=$enc.GetBytes($string)
$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
$ResultHash = $sha1.ComputeHash($data)
$str_out = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ResultHash))
write-host $str_out
```

My guess is that it is using the certificate thumprint as a "key" but I was not able to find a function that encrypts a string in **base64 using a key / passphrase**.

I have tried other functions created to encrypt strings from a certificate, but was unable to find one that matches the one done by Citrix.

I am not good in all the encryption. I only know the very basics so the answer might be obvious and that I can simply not see it due to my lack of skills in that area.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Base64 is simply a data format, not an an encryption method. I assume they're changing the data to Base64 then encrypting it using a cipher/key

Comment: Welcome to SO.  The `Hash (in Active Directory)` looks like `base64encode(kid).base64encode(IV).base64encode(cipherdata)` described in that citrix.com article.  `kid` should be the key ID (thumbprint of the cert).  `IV` is the initialization vector, a unique value (per device) or the first 32 (or 16) bytes of cipher data.  `cipherdata` is the cipher text, or the encrypted structure consisting of a secret, tag, and algorithm.  You should be able to decode the info using the cert (hash + public/private keys).  `\var\netscaler\otptool\main.py` should provide additional clues.  Good luck.